# How to get all controls from tab

Tags: dynamics-crm-2016, xrm

I need to get all controls from a tab on my form, I tried to use this option I found online but it didn't work ideas anyone?

```
var tabs = Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get(); 
var fieldList = new Array();
for (var i in tabs)
{
  var tab = tabs[i];
  if(tab.getName() == "tab_2")
  {
    tab.sections.forEach(function (section, sectionIndex)
    {
      section.controls.forEach(function (control, controlIndex)
      {
        switch (control.getControlType())
        {
          case "standard":
          case "lookup":
          case "optionset":
            var attribute = control.getAttribute();

            if (attribute != null)
            {
              fieldList.push(attribute.getName());
            }
            break;
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your tab called "tab_2"? You've got a conditional `if` block in there checking for that tab name

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the code and it works.
It looks for a tab called **tab_2** and then gets all controls within that tab and adds the `control.name` to an array (`fieldList`)

The result is a simple array of control names. When I ran this on my Contact form (with the `Tab Name` adjusted) I got the following results:

```
[
    "fullname",
    "nickname",
    "employeeid",
    "jobtitle",
    "parentcustomerid",
    "emailaddress1",
    "telephone2",
    "telephone1",
    "mobilephone",
    "fax",
    "address1_composite",
    "preferredsystemuserid",
    "familystatuscode",
    "spousesname",
    "birthdate",
    "description",
    "ownerid",
    "createdon"
]
```

If this is not working for you, I suggest the following:

- Check the name of the CRM Tab
- Depending on where you are running this (e.g. in a web resource or developer console) you may need to change the code context